# pageViewController content jumping

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller

I have a `UIViewController` which I have set as the `UIPageViewControllerDataSource`, as it sits things work great -- with 1 little caveat.  Here's some images to display the issue I have.

[image: First screen within the pageViewController which enters in from the bottom]

[image: Here I am scrolling the content to the second tab. Notice the content is under the status bar.]

[image: Transition done, content jumps down where it should be.]

First image is the first controller in the stack of controllers.  Then, I start to scroll and we see that the content in the next view is under the status bar.  After the scrolling transition is done, we see that the content has now jumped down to its proper place.

In the storyboard, I've unchecked `Adjust Scroll View Insets` on every controller in the stack without success.  I've unchecked everything from every controller in the stack.  I can't seem to find out how to resolve the issues at hand.

My controller stack takes the shape of this:

- Splash Controller ( user clicks create account or login )
- Signup Controller ( an instance of UIViewController)

  - PageViewController ( a UIPageViewController )

    - 8 View Controllers that all inherit from BasePageController which is an instance of UIViewController
- I couldn't get the code to format properly so I added to a gist.

https://gist.github.com/ch0ke/cd0a88da678d6dafe488

Any other code I need to show let me know and I will if I can.  First time using a pageviewcontroller, so all advice is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started looking at other apps that do this, and of course I noticed one similarity between them all.  People seem to have a real issue with this, so take apps like facebook that have a full screen signup flow just like this but everything stays in place..

So how do they do it?  Simple, set the status bar to hidden while in the registration process and re-show it when you're done.